# Create an Outlook Button that opens to a URL

Tags: outlook

I am trying to deploy a specific button within Outlook 2013 that all users can click and opens a specific web page. This fulfills a management request, but my network is highly restricted with macros being disabled. I am not sure that would be something that could be approved. With no budget, addins are out of the question, so I am trying to find an in-house solution.

I was testing some simple VBA on my personal network and this works perfectly:

```
Sub OpenURL()
   x = Shell("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.EXE https://google.com", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

**However is there a non-VBA method to make this work within Outlook 2013?** Thank you for any help!

Comment: How about an exe that launches the url on the default browser if the use?

Comment: Clint, could you explain this more? Can the .exe be integrated into Outlook 2013?

Comment: Without addins or macros thats a very limited scenario

Comment: Clint, thanks. That is what I suspected with this effort.